# PHP - Cannot move PDF file and it's file name to directory path

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

I can't move the pdf file that I uploaded using the name of the pdf file.
My server running IIS. 
 `$file[0] = BOL_BLNUM_COMPANY_TIMESTAMP.pdf` this is the pdf file that I'm trying to move to thhe path: `/AMS/BOL`.

Here is my sample code:

> ```
>       $file = $_FILES['pdf']['name'];
>         $BOL = explode('_', $file[0]);
>       $PL = explode('_', $file[1]);
>         $INVOICE = explode('_', $file[2]); 
>
>       if($BOL[0] == 'BOL'){
>
>           $uploaddir  = "/AMS/BOL";
>
>            $uploadfile = basename( $file[0]) ;
>
>            $ok=1;
>
>           $file_type=$_FILES['pdf']['type'][0];
>           echo $file[0];
>           //die();
>           if ($file_type=="application/pdf") {
>
>            if(move_uploaded_file($file[0], $uploaddir.$uploadfile))
>
>            {
>
>
>               echo 'File uploaded';
>
>            }
>
>            else {
>
>            echo "Problem uploading file";
>
>            }          } }
> ```

Comment: And "I can't" means what actually?

Comment: its echoing "Problem uploading file".

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file say what the issue is?

Comment: Are you uploading multiple files and separating them by `_`?

Comment: yes im uploading multiple files.

Comment: I just see that you are using IIS as http server, so that you are working on a MS-Windows platform. Exotic for a web server, but OK. Then maybe there are no explicit error log files written by the server, but you will find the same entries in the "event console" or however it is currently called in the version of MS-Windows you use. It will hold the same information, only in a more cryptic form than a simple log file.

Comment: @arkascha then how can i fix this?  is it on the folder permission?

Comment: I already told you: read what the issue is in the log file (or event console in your case). Without knowing the cause, how should one say how to fix it?

Comment: did you try dumping $_FILES['pdf'] to see if the file is actually there? Also try to look into the destination folder permissions for your web server's user

Comment: @arkascha `Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php3742.tmp' to '/AMS/BOL/BOL_BLNUM_COMPANY_TIMESTAMP.pdf'`

Comment: @Riccardo yes I tried and the file is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use the tmp_name in move_uploaded_file function instead of name.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$uploadfile)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Put a slash at the end of the $uploaddir such as $uploaddir  = "/AMS/BOL/"; and put the extension of .pdf in $uploadfile such as "$uploadfile = basename( $file[0]) . '.pdf';". Thats because your whole path should reflect the serverp path with filename such as /AMS/BOL/test.pdf. basename only gives you filename without extention.